# Scala Play 2.8 - SwaggerPluggin Failing - com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger, guice

I am using jackson module(com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.13:$jacksonVersion) `2.13.1` with play version `2.8.20`. However getting this error:

```
controllers.SoftwareListControllerSpec > classMethod FAILED
    com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

    1) No implementation for play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPlugin was bound.
      while locating play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPlugin
        for the 2nd parameter of controllers.ApiHelpController.<init>(ApiHelpController.scala:64)
      while locating com.google.inject.Provider<controllers.ApiHelpController>
        for the 7th parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:48)
      at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:139):
    Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: could you provide more details about your context? you started a project from scratch? you upgraded a play project to 2.8? what dependencies or plugins are you using for swagger? To generate a swagger spec in play 2.8 you have [play-swagger/play-swagger](https://github.com/play-swagger/play-swagger) or [dwickern/swagger-play](https://github.com/dwickern/swagger-play). If that doesn't help share more debugging details such as the `application.conf`, `build.sbt`, `plugins.sbt` and how you load the modules

Answer (score 0):

During the time of initialization, while trying to configure the project, I needed to inject the dependency as shown below:

```
bind(classOf[SwaggerPlugin]).to(classOf[SwaggerPluginImpl]).asEagerSingleton()
```

Where the above two classes come from:

`import play.modules.swagger.{SwaggerPlugin, SwaggerPluginImpl}`